# Each word start with capital letter in Edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want that each word should start with capital letter in an Edittext.For example:-

john smith should be write as **John Smith** How can i achieve this?

Comment: For that you have make custom Edittext...

Comment: @Dynamo That's not true at all: android:inputType="textCapWords"

Comment: Not works in my case.

Comment: try to google 1st there are planty of examples available their

Comment: Since it looks like your EditText is for entering names, give a try to textPersonName instead of textCapWords.

Comment: @DeepakSharma you can try programattically my below answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set  `android:inputType="textCapWords"` to your edittext xml.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

to capitalize each word

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

Set
   `android:inputType="textCapSentences" on your EditText.`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

programatically should be like this...

```
EditText etValue = new EditText(this);
etValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this one

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

my be this will work

```
android:capitalize="words"
```

more detail [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3acapitalize)

Comment: it should be "textCapWords" instead since he wants each word to be capital

Comment: @Shrikant is correct.

Comment: Not working in SAMSUNG S3..In other devices it is working fine.